# Redirect to www with .htaccess not redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im have absolutely no experience with .htaccess and i tried something today. I basicly wanted all my pages starting with http://www. to redirect to http://

so i did a search on the internet and found this link :

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2437275

again i had absolutely no idea what i was doing and i just copy pasted this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

into a .htaccess file in my public_html directory

i tested going into a http://www site but nothing happened, so i just deleted everything in the .htaccess file as it was in the beginning, totally bank.

so i tested this

```
# Redirect to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.example\.com)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and then this:

```
# Redirect to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(example\.com)?$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

just like the article says

But now a few hours later i notice something really strange. One of my ajax calls from jquery takes like 1 minute to complete.. Is there anything i can do to undo this? Its almost like something does an infinite loop like the article says. And i have no idea what to do.

Everything works on localhost..

Regards,
Alexander

Comment: "Nothing happened"? No changes to the site? You got a blank page? Why don't you look at the server logs (error and access) to see what's going on? Right now you've provided absolutely nothing of any use in diagnosing your problem(s).

Comment: Have you replaced example.com with your actual domain name?

Comment: It cannot be an infinite loop if it completes in one minute...

Comment: the rewrite works now, i needed to write RewriteEngine on in the beginning but still the ajax call takes forever.. do u guys think it has something to do with me editing the .htaccess file or does it have to be something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to have

```
RewriteEngine on
```

At the beginning of your file.

This may be obvious but since you have no experience, just in case, you have to replace example.com with your domain name.

Be sure you actually have and Apache server.

Be sure to name your file ".htaccess" (with the dot, without the "")

So, this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I really doubt what you did on the .htaccess could slow down the AJAX call, check to see if the .htaccess is now empty, if it is, it will not affect it for sure.

Comment: you are absolutely right thank you so much it works now,but still the ajax call takes forever.. do u guys think it has something to do with me editing the .htaccess file or does it have to be something else?

Comment: its really weird coz it worked just as it should before, and it still works on the localhost.. and the weirdest part is that its only one of the ajax calls.. the rest works fine. i copied the files from localhost just to be sure but still its like this.. its frustrating when mystical stuff like this happens.. i dont even know where to start looking

Comment: @Alexander: I really really doubt it could be related, but if you want to be sure, try commenting out everything on the .htaccess file with `#` if it is still slow, that you are almost certain they are unrelated.

Comment: @Alexander: no problem, glad to help, try to localize you AJAX problem and maybe post another question when you think you got where the problem might rely on. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

**A more optimized version, which don't have domain dependencies**

Just simple copy and paste in any domain and it will work.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```